# Spring Boot Actuator 1.5.10 - missing env Endpoint (404)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am using Spring Boot Version Actuator version 1.5.10.  In my case when I start up the application and access localhost:8080/env I am getting a 404 error response. 
I am able to access common endpoints like `/configprops`,`/beans` etc.  Below is the mapping from the console, Here I am able to see the mapping for other beans but for `/env` , i am able to see env for Post call and not for the Get call. I have tried adding the below things.

```
endpoints.actuator.enabled : true
endpoints.env.enabled: true
endpoints.sensitive: false
endpoints.env : true
endpoints.env.enabled : true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include : 'health,info,beans,env'
management.endpoints.web.expose : '*'
```

This is not working.

PFB the console log

```
2018-09-26 06:41:11.801  INFO [security-v1,,,] 19768 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/actuator || /actuator.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HalJsonMvcEndpoint.links()
2018-09-26 06:41:11.804  INFO [security-v1,,,] 19768 --- [   `enter code here`        main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/mappings || /mappings.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-09-26 06:41:11.805  INFO [security-v1,,,] 19768 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : **Mapped "{[/env],methods=[POST]}"** onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.context.environment.EnvironmentManagerMvcEndpoint.value(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-09-26 06:41:11.808  INFO [security-v1,,,] 19768 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : **Mapped "{[/env/reset],methods=[POST]}"** onto public java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object> org.springframework.cloud.context.environment.EnvironmentManagerMvcEndpoint.reset()
2018-09-26 06:41:11.809  INFO [security-v1,,,] 19768 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/trace || /trace.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-09-26 06:41:11.810  INFO [security-v1,,,] 19768 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/health || /health.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-09-26 06:41:11.812  INFO [security-v1,,,] 19768 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/jolokia/**]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.JolokiaMvcEndpoint.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception
2018-09-26 06:41:11.815  INFO [security-v1,,,] 19768 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics || /metrics.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-09-26 06:41:11.815  INFO [security-v1,,,] 19768 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/hystrix.stream/**]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.cloud.netflix.endpoint.ServletWrappingEndpoint.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception
2018-09-26 06:41:11.816  INFO [security-v1,,,] 19768 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/loggers || /loggers.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-09-26 06:41:11.818  INFO [security-v1,,,] 19768 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/configprops || /configprops.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-09-26 06:41:11.819  INFO [security-v1,,,] 19768 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/refresh || /refresh.json],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.GenericPostableMvcEndpoint.invoke()
2018-09-26 06:41:11.820  INFO [security-v1,,,] 19768 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/heapdump || /heapdump.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/octet-stream]}" onto public void org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HeapdumpMvcEndpoint.invoke(boolean,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException,javax.servlet.ServletException
2018-09-26 06:41:11.821  INFO [security-v1,,,] 19768 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/info || /info.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-09-26 06:41:11.822  INFO [security-v1,,,] 19768 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/service-registry/instance-status],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.cloud.client.serviceregistry.endpoint.ServiceRegistryEndpoint.setStatus(java.lang.String)
2018-09-26 06:41:11.823  INFO [security-v1,,,] 19768 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/service-registry/instance-status],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity org.springframework.cloud.client.serviceregistry.endpoint.ServiceRegistryEndpoint.getStatus()
2018-09-26 06:41:11.825  INFO [security-v1,,,] 19768 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/beans || /beans.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-09-26 06:41:11.828  INFO [security-v1,,,] 19768 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/dump || /dump.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-09-26 06:41:11.829  INFO [security-v1,,,] 19768 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/features || /features.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-09-26 06:41:11.831  INFO [security-v1,,,] 19768 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/autoconfig || /autoconfig.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-09-26 06:41:11.832  INFO [security-v1,,,] 19768 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/archaius || /archaius.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
```

Comment: Looks like you are using Spring cloud. Can you post your pom.xml

Comment: As you said the `/env/` for HTTP GET is not mapped at all, but from the latest github src code [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/env/EnvironmentEndpoint.java) it seems that the GET method is indeed exposed. If its feasible , could you change the logging threshold to debug and post the overall logs to check why you're getting the failure. Or else try to upgrade to the latest release.